# Which solution is the best regarding the time of a SELECT request?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I was wondering what is the best solution regarding this problem :

I have articles, and I have categories, an article belongs to a category. There are two types of categories, user defined and system defined (like "inbox","trash" etc ...)

So the question is should I have only one item for each system defined categories, and all the articles of all the users will be attached to these categories, or should I create all the systems defined categories when creating the user, and attached these categories to the user ?

The first solution will result in a lot of articles in each system defined categories, and the second solution will result in a lot of "redundant" item in category. Which solution is the best ?

Answer (score 0):

It's your choice. Both approaches has its pros and cons.
If you go with the first solution, your select statement will have a `WHERE` clause similar to this:

```
WHERE (category.type = 'SYSTEM' OR category.user_id = :USER_ID)
```

The second solution will simplify your select statements:

```
WHERE category.user_id = :USER_ID
```

The second solution will make it more complex to add a user. You need to create the system defined categories for the user:

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORY (user_id, category_name, ...)  SELECT :USER_ID, system_category, ... FROM SYSTEM CATEGORY;
```

And if you add a new system category you need to insert it for all users.